# Replacing a .js File on a Website

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

So I'm trying to replace a javascript file on a website. I have tried using tamper monkey and developer tools, but none of them work? Thanks.

Original code

```
getAvatarUrl: function(avatar, type) {
         if (!manifest[avatar]) 
            avatar = 'base01'; 
            var version = manifest[avatar][type]; 
            return base_url + "/" + avatar + type + "." + version + ".png"; 
}
```

Overridden code

```
getAvatarUrl: function() { 
   return "Custom Image url"; 
}
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: Sorry for being vague. Im trying to replace a .js file that handles avatars so i can load custom avatars on the site

Comment: still not clear.. what do you mean by `replace a .js file` like deletion or overriding the functions something like that? can you please provide some relevant code and what problem you are facing

Comment: Yes, overiding functions, sorry I'm very new to javascript. I would like to add a new .js file with the same functions

Comment: ok..np.. please provide some relevant code and what problem you are facing while overriding particular functionality

Comment: My code `getAvatarUrl: function()
        {
            
            return "Custom Image url";
        },`

original code ` getAvatarUrl: function(avatar, type)
        {
            if (!manifest[avatar]) avatar = 'base01';
            var version = manifest[avatar][type];
            return base_url + "/" + avatar + type + "." + version + ".png";
        }`

Comment: you need to give more info, are both functions are in same scope or original function is enclosed in different scope, in short is it global function

Comment: @vinayakj I just realized that javascript uses the last found function so i can just add a new .js file, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Add the overridden code after the original code, as javascript interprets line by line. So add below code

```
getAvatarUrl: function() { 
   return "Custom Image url"; 
}
```

After

```
getAvatarUrl: function(avatar, type) {
         if (!manifest[avatar]) 
            avatar = 'base01'; 
            var version = manifest[avatar][type]; 
            return base_url + "/" + avatar + type + "." + version + ".png"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to replace the entire file, if you simply include another file after the other files, like `<script src="path/to/script.js"></src>` you can override the old function by declaring a new function:

```
function getAvatarUrl(){
    return "Custom Image URL";
}
```